# Parallelize inference with huggingface using torch

Tags: pytorch, parallel-processing, out-of-memory, batch-processing, huggingface

I am running an inference model on a Ubuntu machine with 8GB only and just realised the predictions (logits) are not generated in a batch way so my process is getting Killed due oom issues.

```
tokenized_test = tokenizer(dataset["test"]["text"], padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**tokenized_test).logits
```

This is where I run out of memory. What is the best way of do this in batches/parallelize/sequentiate/solve the oom issue. I am ultimately looking for the solution that would require the least amount of code changes.

---

#### Source

I have built my code based on this tutorial:

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/sequence_classification

Increasing the dataset size will eventually make you go oom to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting test set to `TensorDataset` and then use `DataLoader`. somthing like this:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset

batch_size = 32

test_dataset = TensorDataset(*[tokenized_test[key] for key in tokenized_test])
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

with torch.no_grad():
    logits_list = []
    for batch in test_dataloader:
        batch_logits = model(*batch).logits
        logits_list.append(batch_logits)

logits = torch.cat(logits_list)
```